# How to remove Z from xml timestamp input using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

My input XML:

```
<chatTranscript startAt="2017-06-28T20:00:17Z">
<message>hai</message>
</chatTranscript>
```

in the input timestamp it contains Z. But Z should removed in the output XML like below:

```
<chat>
<time>2017-06-28T20:00:17</time>
</chat>
```

Answer (score 1):

XPath 2.0 has a function for that:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/chatTranscript">
    <chat>
        <time>
            <xsl:value-of select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(@startAt, ())"/>
        </time>
    </chat>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```